# Which action is triggered before final output?

Tags: functions

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

When I use `add_action('init','myfunc')`, at that moment the variables (`is_404()` or other) are not yet detected. When is best time to detect `is_404()`, `$post->post_type`, and all WordPress variables? Of course I want to trigger function(which sets php HEADERS) before output starts.

## EDIT:

So far, i have found :

1) `add_action('AFTER_THEME_SETUP','myfunc')` and `add_action('wp','myfunc')` to work before template files are loaded, but these actions only work on normal wordpress pages (although not in custom injected external php files,where you may use include('wp-load.php');

2) `add_action('wp_loaded','myfunc')` is good also, but at that time, $post variable is not yet loaded ((.

Comment: Please properly format your code, add code in back ticks or an code block, depending which is applicable to the situation. Do not use bold lettering to display code. Also, what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

I often use `template_redirect`. You can also try `wp`. [List of WP Actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

Comment: WOW. Good. but Please, modify your answer, and instead **wp_loaded**, enter **wp**, and i will mark your answer as best. (because **wp_loaded** doesnt seem to catch $post object)